# Confusion regarding specific conductivity

Tags: electrochemistry

Is there any difference between the terms specific conductivity and conductance. If yes, please explain.

Comment: probably belongs to physics segment

Comment: It could be answered here, since conductivity is a measurement often applied to solution chemistry and materials science.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry Stack Exchange! Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a wire inside cable for example. That wire's **conductance** is just the inverse of the resistance this cable is making when electricity passes through it. This depends on things like the length, what is made of, the maximum/minimum width of certain areas of the wire, etc.

On the other hand, the **conductivity** of that wire is a direct property of the material it's made of. If the wire is made of copper for example, it'll have (at the same temperature) the same *conductivity* as any copper wire in the world (because they are all made of copper), but not the same *conductance* (because they are not physically equal)

I hope this helps, I'm sorry if I was wrong!